# Printing only when it is not an empty string

Tags: string, ocaml, record

Assume that

```
type house = {first_name: string; last_name: string; nb_windows: int; nb_doors: int; nb_cars: int; nb_rooms: int};;
house1 = {first_name="John"; last_name="Doe; nb_windows = 10; nb_doors = 50; nb_cars = 3; nb_rooms= 10};;
```

I want to print each element of record `house1`.

```
Full Name : John Doe
Number of windows : 10
Number of doors : 50
Number of cars : 3
Number of rooms : 10
```

A way I have define the function is

```
let test (lch: house) = 
    begin
      print_string ("Full Name : " ^ lch.first_name ^ " " ^ lch.last_name "\n");
      print_string ("Number of windows : " ^ string_of_int lch.nb_windows ^ "\n");
      print_string ("Number of doors : " ^ string_of_int lch.nb_doors ^ "\n");
      print_string ("Number of car : " ^ string_of_int lch.nb_cars ^ "\n");
      print_string ("Number of rooms : " ^ string_of_int lch.nb_rooms ^ "\n\n");
    end;;

test house1;;
```

However, that function is very limited. For instance, if I define

```
house2 = {first_name=""; last_name="" nb_windows=10; nb_doors = 50; nb_cars = 3; nb_rooms= 10}
```

In that example, I don't want to print `Full Name` if `first_name` and `last_name` are emptied strings.

How can I modify the `test` function so that the line `test house2;;` will display only

```
Number of windows : 10
Number of doors : 50
Number of cars : 3
Number of rooms : 10
```

instead of

```
Full Name :
Number of windows : 10
Number of doors : 50
Number of cars : 3
Number of rooms : 10
```

Be aware that I have to use only the functional paradigm, so no `while` or `for` loops.

**Beginning of an answer**

I think I can use something like

```
let print_data x y = match x with
      | "" -> ()
      | x -> print_string y;;
```

but I don't know how to move on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `print_data` tests one string to determine whether to print another string. You can use this function if you pass `lch.first_name ^ lch.last_name` as the test string, and your desired output string as the second string.

Specifically, replace this line:

```
  print_string ("Full Name : " ^ lch.first_name ^ " " ^ lch.last_name "\n");
```

With this instead:

```
print_data (lch.first_name ^ lch.last_name)
    ("Full Name : " ^ lch.first_name ^ " " ^ lch.last_name "\n");
```

For what it's worth, this is just programming and doesn't have much to do with OCaml in particular (IMHO).

As some unsolicited advice: if your problem is that you can't look at `print_data` and figure out how it works, the thing to do is to go through an OCaml tutorial or two until you can understand the language more easily. This will be faster than asking individual questions here on StackOverflow.

**Update**

Here's a function that formats only the non-null strings that it is given:

```
let concat_non_null strings =
    String.concat " " (List.filter ((<>) "") strings)
```

To print the name:

```
match concat_non_null [lch.first_name; lch.last_name] with
| "" -> ()
| s -> print_endline ("Full_name: " ^ s)
```

You could argue that this generalizes fairly well to more names--when there's also a middle name, say.

Comment: `print_data (lch.first_name ^ lch.last_name)("Full Name : " ^ lch.first_name ^ " " ^ lch.last_name "\n");;` is quite repetitive because `lch.first_name` and `lch.last_name` are repeated twice. Do you have a solution prevent this from happening? I found another solution, but I got the same problem. Let me write my solution as an answer. It will be shown in a few minutes

Comment: I would say, again, that this is just programming :-) But also, producing nicely formatted output is, in general, maddening and full of code that's hard to generalize.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Do you have a solution to prevent the code from repeating twice? It is very annoying and unnecessary. Imagine `print_data (lch.a1 ^ lch.a2 ^ ... ^ lch.a_n) (...)`.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to avoid testing and printing as two separate appearances of the names. This is especially the case since what you want to print is subtly different from what you want to test.

Comment: Can you explain to me what is the meaning of `((<>) "")`? It seems equivalent to a undefined function `(fun x -> x <> "")`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes `((<>) "")` has the same meaning as `(fun s -> s <> "")`. I don't know why you call it "undefined" -- maybe a typo? Or maybe you mean it doesn't come predefined in OCaml? Anyway you can convert any operator to a prefix function by putting it in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
let print_data a b =
  let has_empty_string list_strings = List.exists (fun x -> x = "") list_strings in
  match a with 
  | [] -> ()
  | _ -> if not (has_empty_string a) then print_string b else ();;

print_data [lch.first_name, lch.last_name] ("Full Name : " ^ lch.first_name ^ " " ^ lch.last_name "\n");;
```

This works, but `lch.first_name` and `lch.last_name` are repeated twich, which is a bit annoying.